# Convert HTTPS cookie into an OAUTH2 token

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0

I am working on a data project where I need to pass an HTTPS cookie into an OAUTH2 API. I was planning on trying to convert the cookie into a token but am not finding too much information on this. Any help or guidance on how this might be accomplished would be wonderful.